# How to return pointer to an array position in array pointed to by void*?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, void-pointers

I have a queue that is an array of chars, pointed to by a void pointer named `data`, this holds the correct address of `0x00008E80`.

The tail of the queue is tracked by a simple index integer, in this case it is equal to `6`, i.e. the 7th array position.

I'd like to return a pointer to the tail array position, which should be `0x00008E86`.

I've tried the following (and some variations thereof) with no luck:

```
struct queue_t {
    void * data;
    uint16_t tail;
};
char sqData[SQ_LENGTH] = {0};
struct queue_t sq = {0};

void initQueue (queue_t * q, void * d) {
    q->data = d;
}

char * getTailPositionAddress (context_t sc) {
    char * s = (char *)sc->slave->queue->data;
    return (s + sc->slave->queue->tail);
}

void main (void) {
    initQueue(&sq, sqData);
    foo_context->slave->queue = &sq;
    // queue is of type struct queue_t *

    // Do some stuff that pushes data to the queue and then pops a bit of it
    //  so the tail is moved up to the 7th array position
    char * bar = getTailPositionAddress(fooContext);
    // Here bar is always equal to some stupid low address like 0x5 or 0x2!?!
}
```

Why isn't this working? What would be the correct way to achieve what is intended? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say this doesn't work ? Can you be more specific ? Did you try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what's going on ?

Comment: `return sc->slave->queue->tail;` ?

Comment: if `tail` is an integer of some sort then your code is fine and 0x5 or 0x2 are the values pointed by the bar pointer.

Comment: Show the definitions.

Comment: @someuser of the queue struct? added in question now.

Comment: @PaulR my IDE (Eclipse CDT) doesn't seem to be letting me see what `s` is set to when I step (prob because I've optimization turned on, can't turn of as program won't fit on device then). But stepping the assembly seems to result in the correct values being calculated. The value returned doesn't seem to change `bar` at all however.

Comment: Question down vote? for why?

Comment: how do you know the value of `bar`?

Comment: @n.m. Halting the debugger at this point shows the value of `bar` in it's variables window... hmmm, hold on...

Comment: if the optimizations are on it means nothing. The compiler is free to delay writing the value to memory or elide it altogether. You should either output the variable to a file or declare it volatile if you want to examine it.

Comment: @n.m. Bingo! Forgot the darn optimizer effects, gah! When the variable is used later on it goes back and sets it to the correct value. Thanks!!

Comment: @n.m. If you'd like to make your comment an answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Still puzzled by the question down vote though ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted program doesn't allow to see what  value `bar` gets in the end, even with a debugger. The compiler is free to rearrange memory writes such that the value is stored in memory long after it's calculated. The compiler can even elide storing it altogether, especially when optimizations are in use.

In order to be able to examine the value of `bar`, it should be either declared `volatile` or sent to a file. Declaring it `volatile` guarantees the value will be stored in memory *eventually* --- not necessarily right after it's computed, but before any other observable event takes place.